# How to set bounding box in mapsforge just like in osmdroid and how do I put a text above or below the pathLayer?

Tags: android, android-studio, mapsforge

How to set bounding box in mapsforge just like in osmdroid and how do I put a text above or below the pathLayer?

In osmdroid, I usually call the `setScrollableAreaLimit()` method but in mapsforge there's no such method in the `mapView`. How do I accomplish this?

And also how do I add a `TextOverlay` below or above the `PathLayer`?

```
//Bounding Box
maxScrollableLimit = new BoundingBox(14.7882,121.1421,14.3469,120.8990);

...

private PathLayer createPathLayerFirst(PathWrapper response) {
    Style style = Style.builder()
            .generalization(Style.GENERALIZATION_SMALL)
            .strokeColor(0x9900cc33)
            .strokeWidth(4 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density)
            .build();
    PathLayer pathLayer = new PathLayer(mapView.map(), style);
    List<GeoPoint> geoPoints = new ArrayList<>();
    PointList pointList = response.getPoints();
    for (int i = 0; i < pointList.getSize(); i++)
        geoPoints.add(new GeoPoint(pointList.getLatitude(i), pointList.getLongitude(i)));
    pathLayer.setPoints(geoPoints);
    return pathLayer;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the code you provide, it is not clear if you looked at the [mapsforge docs](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/blob/master/docs/Getting-Started-Android-App.md) at all. Do so first, then return to my answer.

For setting map limits, add the following code to your onStart() method:

```
mapView.getModel().mapViewPosition.setMapLimit(this.getBoundingBox());
```

And in the same class, have the following method ready:

```
private BoundingBox getBoundingBox() {
    final double MINLAT = Double.valueOf(res.getString(R.string.mapminlat));
    final double MINLON = Double.valueOf(res.getString(R.string.mapminlon));
    final double MAXLAT = Double.valueOf(res.getString(R.string.mapmaxlat));
    final double MAXLON = Double.valueOf(res.getString(R.string.mapmaxlon));
    return new BoundingBox(MINLAT, MINLON, MAXLAT, MAXLON);
}
```

For adding a layer to your mapview do the following:

```
mapView.getLayerManager().getLayers().add(layer);
```

For creating a layer, see the docs. Take a special look at the [examples](https://github.com/mapsforge/mapsforge/tree/master/mapsforge-samples-android/src/main/java/org/mapsforge/samples/android); maybe the LabelLayer is what you are looking for.